# python script generates this error: numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError:

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, memory-management

Background Info:

- OS: Ubuntu
- RAM: 128GB
- Language: Python
- Task: NLP project

Below is the full error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/noone/Documents/GitHub/feedback_prize/training.py", line 20, in <module>
    train_df = df[df["kfold"] != args.fold].reset_index(drop=True)  # this error has me a bit stumped. all my web searches come back with this being related to acually exceeding memory limits. Initially I thought i was different and i read it again. 155GB is > 125 avaiilable
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/common.py", line 69, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/arraylike.py", line 36, in __ne__
    return self._cmp_method(other, operator.ne)
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 6851, in _cmp_method
    self, other = ops.align_method_FRAME(self, other, axis, flex=False, level=None)
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py", line 306, in align_method_FRAME
    left, right = left.align(
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 4677, in align
    return super().align(
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8591, in align
    return self._align_series(
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 8714, in _align_series
    fdata = fdata.reindex_indexer(join_index, lidx, axis=bm_axis)
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 676, in reindex_indexer
    new_blocks = self._slice_take_blocks_ax0(
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 782, in _slice_take_blocks_ax0
    self._make_na_block(placement=mgr_locs, fill_value=fill_value)
  File "/home/noone/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_NLP/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py", line 836, in _make_na_block
    block_values = np.empty(block_shape, dtype=dtype)  # type: ignore[arg-type]
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 155. GiB for an array with shape (144293, 144293) and data type float64
```

I have 128GB RAM on my system. I am surprised that this would require 155GB, but that's how I read it. As a temporary solution, I tried to swap memory with one of my M2 drives. I partitioned 1TB for this purpose. Unfortunately after doing so, the same error occurs. I am quite sure i set up the swap memory correctly.

I am concerned that I am misreading this, and the problem is not actually memory, it is code related, although i find that difficult to accept as its just a pandas operation. Nothing fancy.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide more info.

thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, I've resolved it. I added the swapfile information to /etc/fstab file and restarted. That seemed to do the trick, for now at least. Thank you and sorry for the bother

Comment: 155Gb is consistent with the dimensions (144293, 144293)

Comment: Might be good to put the resolution in as an answer rather than a comment Michael?